# Graticule will not display in layout view

Tags: arcmap, layouts, grids-graticules

**Problem:**

I am trying to create a graticule for a map in **ArcMap 10.7.1**. When I create the graticule and hit "apply", the graticule does not display in layout view or when I export the map.

Steps to create the graticule:

- View -> Data frame properties -> Grids
- New Grid -> Graticule -> Labels Only -> 5 degree meridians / parallels
- Etc.

**Attempts to resolve:**

- Changing the Label Offset point value to at least half the Label Size ([from here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000008120)).
- Defining a coordinate system for the data frame ([from here](https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000005333)).
- Turn on grid (View -> Grid)

I have tried reducing intervals to minutes or seconds, but graticules are still not appearing.

Comment: There are no five-degree meridians or parallels at the extent of your layout?

Comment: Try reducing your grid interval to minutes or even seconds, depending on the scale of your map.

Comment: My map is a map of southeastern Canada, so it includes Nova Scotia, New Brunswick, PEI, and parts of Maine (USA). I've tried reducing grid intervals to minutes or seconds, still not appearing.

Comment: What coordinate system is the map using and what are you using for the graticule?  Try 1° separation if you're setting it to a geographic coordinate system. As @GBG asked are the lines drawing? I would ignore/turn off the labels for now.

Answer (score 0):

My shapefiles had different coordinate systems. When I changed the coordinate systems of my shapefiles in ArcMap, I lost my graticules.

To fix this, I changed the coordinate system of the shapefile before dragging it into the map (i.e. changed coordinate system in catalog view). The graticule now displays in layout view.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. I misunderstood and put numbers in the dec,degree,minutes boxes (where it asks you twice right on top of the other) and my graticules disappeared. When I went back and left decimal,degree,minutes as 0's, the grid popped back up.